# django.utils.datastructures.MultiValueDictKeyError: 'password'

Tags: python, django

I'm using Django3 and Python 3. I'm trying to create registration and login pages. My registration part is successful. I can put data into the database table. But when it comes to login part, I'm getting an error
This is my view file:

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.contrib.auth.models import auth
from firstapp.models import Customers

def home(request):
    return render(request, 'home.html')


def register(request):
    return render(request, 'register.html')


def reg_success(request):
    name = request.POST['name']
    username = request.POST['username']
    password = request.POST['password']
    email = request.POST['email']
    mobile = request.POST['mobile']
    # return HttpResponse("<h2>UserRegistered Successfully</h2>")
    if request.method == 'POST':
        user = Customers.objects.create(name=name, username=username, password=password, email=email, mobile=mobile)
        user.save()
        print("User Created")
        return render(request, 'reg_success.html', {'username': username})
    else:
        return render(request, 'register.html')


def login(request):
    return render(request, 'login.html')


def log_success(request):
    username = request.POST['username']
    password = request.POST['password']
    if request.method == 'POST':
        user = auth.authenticate(username=username, password=password)

        if user is not None:
            auth.login(request, user)
            return render(request, 'log_success.html', {'username': username})
        else:
            return HttpResponse("Invalid Details Given")
            #return redirect(login)
    else:
        return redirect(login)
```

This is my HTML file `log_success.html`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Login Success</title>
</head>
<body>

<form method="post">
{% csrf_token %}
<h2 style="color:green">Welcome {{username}}</h2>
<p>Here is Your Bio Data</p>
<a href="/">Logout</a>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

This is my urls file

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.home, name="home"),
    path('register', views.register, name="register"),
    path('reg_success', views.reg_success, name="reg_success"),
    path('login', views.login, name="login"),
    path('log_success', views.log_success, name="log_success"),
]
```

Here is the traceback of the error: TODO

Here are the steps I've tried to fix it: TODO

Comment: It means `request.POST` does not contains a value for `'password'`.

Comment: heyyy... Thanks bro i forgot to give name="password" in login.html what a silly mistake i did. :)